# MYSQL Loading null values from text file input

Tags: mysql

I'm making a toy application for the purpose of learning about mysql databases where I am trying to store properties of [Magic The Gathering Cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic:_The_Gathering) as records in the following format:

> mtgo_id | card_name | mana_cost | cmc | card_type | oracle_text | card_power | card_toughness | rarity

I am having trouble assigning null values to fields using `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`. I have seen the other solutions on stack overflow that suggest using `SET` which work, however I would like to know where I am going wrong interpreting the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) about escaped characters, since I am setting my null fields to '\N' like instructed in my text file.

Here is an example record from the text file:

```
82955    Disenchant      {1}{W}      2.0     Instant     Destroy target artifact or enchantment.     \N      \N      common
```

The load data query:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "/path/ZNRrecords.txt" INTO TABLE znrTake1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ENCLOSED BY '' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r' STARTING BY ''
```

This produces the following where I get "N" instead of null:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my problem, I was using extra spaces when writing my records to the txt file.

so

```
records.write("%s \t %s \t %s \t %s \t ....)
```

instead of

```
records.write("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

From the official documentation

> Backslash is the MySQL escape character within strings in SQL
> statements.

So in your file that you load from, instead for just `\N` put `\\N` in order for Null to be parsed as `\N`.

Also you can use this

```sql
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "/path/ZNRrecords.txt"
INTO TABLE znrTake1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
ENCLOSED BY '' 
ESCAPED BY '\\' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r'
STARTING BY ''
(mtgo_id, card_name, mana_cost, cmc, card_type, oracle_text, @vcard_power, @vcard_toughness, rarity)
SET
card_power = NULLIF(@vcard_power,'\N'),
card_toughness = NULLIF(@vcard_toughness,'\N');
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the response! I tried what you suggested and now end up with "\N" as my field value. I am using `r"\\N"` in python when writing to my record txt file, should I use a different statement?

Comment: Hi! Can you post he exact command that you execute to write to the file?